# jquery_accordion.js code needed for nested accordions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I just want everyone to know that I am new to coding, especially JS.  I am capable at HTML and CSS, beyond that I am clueless. However, I am very good at following instructions.
I have spent days researching and still am clueless as to how to fix my problem...I have read that you cannot have multiple accordions open, but I have seen it done...I just don't know how.
I am using jquery_accordion.js for a FAQ page.
This is the coding I have at the top of my faq.page.liquid template.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ 'jquery_accordion.js' | asset_url }}"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.accordion').accordion({

cookieName: 'accordion_nav'
});
});
</script>
```

```js
/**
 * Accordion, jQuery Plugin
 *
 * This plugin provides an accordion with cookie support.
 *

 * @version 1.1
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.accordion = function(options) {

        //firewalling
        if (!this || this.length < 1) {
            return this;
        }

        initialize(this, options);

    };

    //create the initial accordion
    function initialize(obj, options) {

        //build main options before element iteration
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.accordion.defaults, options);

        //store any opened default values to set cookie later
        var opened = '';

        //iterate each matched object, bind, and open/close
        obj.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            saveOpts($this, opts);

            //bind it to the event
            if (opts.bind == 'mouseenter') {
                $this.bind('mouseenter', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    toggle($this, opts);
                });
            }

            //bind it to the event
            if (opts.bind == 'mouseover') {
                $this.bind('mouseover',function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    toggle($this, opts);
                });
            }

            //bind it to the event
            if (opts.bind == 'click') {
                $this.bind('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    toggle($this, opts);
                });
            }

            //bind it to the event
            if (opts.bind == 'dblclick') {
                $this.bind('dblclick', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    toggle($this, opts);
                });
            }

            //initialize the panels
            //get the id for this element
            id = $this.attr('id');

            //if not using cookies, open defaults
            if (!useCookies(opts)) {
                //close it if not defaulted to open
                if (id != opts.defaultOpen) {
                    $this.addClass(opts.cssClose);
                    opts.loadClose($this, opts);
                } else { //its a default open, open it
                    $this.addClass(opts.cssOpen);
                    opts.loadOpen($this, opts);
                    opened = id;
                }
            } else { //can use cookies, use them now
                //has a cookie been set, this overrides default open
                if (issetCookie(opts)) {
                    if (inCookie(id, opts) === false) {
                        $this.addClass(opts.cssClose);
                        opts.loadClose($this, opts);
                    } else {
                        $this.addClass(opts.cssOpen);
                        opts.loadOpen($this, opts);
                        opened = id;
                    }
                } else { //a cookie hasn't been set open defaults
                    if (id != opts.defaultOpen) {
                        $this.addClass(opts.cssClose);
                        opts.loadClose($this, opts);
                    } else { //its a default open, open it
                        $this.addClass(opts.cssOpen);
                        opts.loadOpen($this, opts);
                        opened = id;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        //now that the loop is done, set the cookie
        if (opened.length > 0 && useCookies(opts)) {
            setCookie(opened, opts);
        } else { //there are none open, set cookie
            setCookie('', opts);
        }

        return obj;
    };

    //load opts from object
    function loadOpts($this) {
        return $this.data('accordion-opts');
    }

    //save opts into object
    function saveOpts($this, opts) {
        return $this.data('accordion-opts', opts);
    }

    //hides a accordion panel
    function close(opts) {
        opened = $(document).find('.' + opts.cssOpen);
        $.each(opened, function() {
            //give the proper class to the linked element
            $(this).addClass(opts.cssClose).removeClass(opts.cssOpen);
            opts.animateClose($(this), opts);
        });
    }

    //opens a accordion panel
    function open($this, opts) {
        close(opts);
        //give the proper class to the linked element
        $this.removeClass(opts.cssClose).addClass(opts.cssOpen);

        //open the element
        opts.animateOpen($this, opts);

        //do cookies if plugin available
        if (useCookies(opts)) {
            // split the cookieOpen string by ","
            id = $this.attr('id');
            setCookie(id, opts);
        }
    }

    //toggle a accordion on an event
    function toggle($this, opts) {
        // close the only open item
        if ($this.hasClass(opts.cssOpen))
        {
            close(opts);
            //do cookies if plugin available
            if (useCookies(opts)) {
                // split the cookieOpen string by ","
                setCookie('', opts);
            }
            return false;
        }
        close(opts);
        //open a closed element
        open($this, opts);
        return false;
    }

    //use cookies?
    function useCookies(opts) {
        //return false if cookie plugin not present or if a cookie name is not provided
        if (!$.cookie || opts.cookieName == '') {
            return false;
        }

        //we can use cookies
        return true;
    }

    //set a cookie
    function setCookie(value, opts)
    {
        //can use the cookie plugin
        if (!useCookies(opts)) { //no, quit here
            return false;
        }

        //cookie plugin is available, lets set the cookie
        $.cookie(opts.cookieName, value, opts.cookieOptions);
    }

    //check if a accordion is in the cookie
    function inCookie(value, opts)
    {
        //can use the cookie plugin
        if (!useCookies(opts)) {
            return false;
        }

        //if its not there we don't need to remove from it
        if (!issetCookie(opts)) { //quit here, don't have a cookie
            return false;
        }

        //unescape it
        cookie = unescape($.cookie(opts.cookieName));

        //is this value in the cookie arrray
        if (cookie != value) { //no, quit here
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    //check if a cookie is set
    function issetCookie(opts)
    {
        //can we use the cookie plugin
        if (!useCookies(opts)) { //no, quit here
            return false;
        }

        //is the cookie set
        if ($.cookie(opts.cookieName) == null) { //no, quit here
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // settings
    $.fn.accordion.defaults = {
        cssClose: 'accordion-close', //class you want to assign to a closed accordion header
        cssOpen: 'accordion-open', //class you want to assign an opened accordion header
        cookieName: 'accordion', //name of the cookie you want to set for this accordion
        cookieOptions: { //cookie options, see cookie plugin for details
            path: '/',
            expires: 7,
            domain: '',
            secure: ''
        },
        defaultOpen: '', //id that you want opened by default
        speed: 'slow', //speed of the slide effect
        bind: 'click', //event to bind to, supports click, dblclick, mouseover and mouseenter
        animateOpen: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideDown with custom function
            elem.next().stop(true, true).slideDown(opts.speed);
        },
        animateClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideUp with custom function
            elem.next().stop(true, true).slideUp(opts.speed);
        },
        loadOpen: function (elem, opts) { //replace the default open state with custom function
            elem.next().show();
        },
        loadClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the default close state with custom function
            elem.next().hide();
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.accordion {
margin: 0;
padding:10px;
border-top:#000000 2px solid;
background: #ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
color: #000000;
font-size:1em;
position:relative;
}
.accordion-open {
background:#cccccc;
color: #ffffff;
}
.accordion-open span {
display:block;
position:absolute;
right:3px;
top:25%;
padding:10px;
}
.accordion-open span {
background:url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0276/6855/t/14/assets/minus.png?4342') center center no-repeat;
}
.accordion-close span {
display:block;
position:absolute;
right:3px;
top:25%;
background:url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0276/6855/t/14/assets/plus.png?4342') center center no-repeat;
padding:10px;
}
.faqpage div.container {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.faqpage div.container {
max-width:100%;
padding:5px 0;
}
.faqpage div.content {
background:#cccccc;
margin: 0;
padding:10px;
color: #000000;
font-size:.9em;
line-height:1.5em;
}
.faqpage div.content ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
padding:3px;
}
.faqpage div.content p {
padding:0;
margin:3px 0 10px;
padding:3px;
}
.faqpage div.content ul li {
list-style-position:inside;
line-height:25px;
}
 
</style>
```

```html
<div class="accordion" id="section1">CATEGORY 1<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="accordion" id="section2"><strong>Nested Question 1</strong> <span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to question 1.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section3">Nested Question 2<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to nested question 2.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section4">Nested Question 3<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to nested question 3.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section1">CATEGORY 2<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="accordion" id="section2"><strong>Nested Question 1</strong> <span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to question 1.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section3">Nested Question 2<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to nested question 2.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section4">Nested Question 3<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to nested question 3.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section1">CATEGORY 3<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="accordion" id="section2"><strong>Nested Question 1</strong> <span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to question 1.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section3">Nested Question 2<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to nested question 2.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section4">Nested Question 3<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to nested question 3.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Everything shows up correctly, but when you click on a nested accordion it brings it up for a split second then closes the main accordion too.
Please remember I am very new to all of this.  Any help with exactly what needs deleted or added and where will be greatly appreciated! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are the accordions closing ? :

```
//hides a accordion panel
function close(opts) {
    opened = $(document).find('.' + opts.cssOpen);
    $.each(opened, function() {
        //give the proper class to the linked element
        $(this).addClass(opts.cssClose).removeClass(opts.cssOpen);
        opts.animateClose($(this), opts);
    });
}

//opens a accordion panel
function open($this, opts) {
    close(opts, true); // Pass a variable to the close function (That variable only will be passed from here)
    // As you see the open function calls close function that 
    // close all acordions before open the selected.
    .......
}
```

You can rewrite that parts of code to satisfy your needs.

### EDIT

Also if you want to keep opened only the parent accordion of nested acordions you have to know if an accordion is inside another accordion. (You need to know id, class or something that identifies the accordion -- in your case each accordion has the class `.accordion`). See below:

```
function close(opts) {
    opened = $(document).find('.' + opts.cssOpen);
    $.each(opened, function() {
        //give the proper class to the linked element
        if(opened.find('.accordion').length == 0 && aux){
          // Now with the aux variable will only close the dialog if 
          // we click to open one. 
          // Accordion with nested found -- Don't close it
        } else {
          $(this).addClass(opts.cssClose).removeClass(opts.cssOpen);
          opts.animateClose($(this), opts);
        }
    });
}
```

Try it and let me know if you have errors! =)

### EDIT 2

I've copied all your code and I have make it work now!
Basically when you click to open a accordion you pass the id of the clicked accordion to the close function. Now we find the next element of the clicked accordion wich is the container. Find in the container if it has the element of the clicked accordion. If yes do nothing(don't close), else close it.

```
function open($this, opts) {
    close(opts, $this.attr('id'));
    ...

function close(opts, id_open) {
    opened = $(document).find('.' + opts.cssOpen);
    $.each(opened, function() {
      console.log(id_open, $(this).next().find('[id="' + id_open + '"]').length);
      if($(this).next().find('[id="' + id_open + '"]').length){
        // You have clicked in a accordion, let's see if the next element --(class container)
        // has the element with id="idOfClickedAccordion" -- If it has don't close
      } else {
        $(this).addClass(opts.cssClose).removeClass(opts.cssOpen);
        opts.animateClose($(this), opts);
      }
    });
}
```

Also will be cool if you change the ids of each accordion:

```
<div class="accordion" id="section1_1">CATEGORY 1<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="accordion" id="section1_2"><strong>Nested Question 1</strong> <span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to question 1.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section1_3">Nested Question 2<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to nested question 2.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section1_4">Nested Question 3<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to nested question 3.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section2_1">CATEGORY 2<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="accordion" id="section2_2"><strong>Nested Question 1</strong> <span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to question 1.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section2_3">Nested Question 2<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to nested question 2.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion" id="section2_4">Nested Question 3<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Answer to nested question 3.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this help!  It works in the sense that it will now allow my nested accordions to be opened, but now I can't close any of them.  Any help?

Comment: See my edited code. I think this should work! Let me know if not! You're welcome!

Comment: Using the edited code, now it will only open one accordion. After you open one, it will no longer open any other. It won't close that one either.  I greatly appreciate your help!!

Comment: Ummm I am thinking on make cache of opened accordions i will elaborate my answer tomorrow...

Comment: Thank you again...I don't know if I'm not adding the code in the correct place or if I'm doing something else wrong, but now it won't open the nested accordions (it closes everything again).

Comment: I've created a fiddle just to show you that it works and how you have to structure the code... https://jsfiddle.net/k1p4uLfL/

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what I was doing wrong, but when I copied the whole JS code from the fiddle it works perfectly!  THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as correct so that other people with similar problems know that's correct answer!

Comment: I just did.  (I didn't know that I could mark it as correct)  I'm learning about this website too.  THANKS again for all of your help!

Comment: Yes!! :D You can vote up and down and/or mark answer as correct!! Thank you too!!